# loading firefox specific css for a different background

Tags: jquery, css

Here's the deal, I have a jQuery plugin I am using that works best in Safari and Chrome..  It slows down Firefox.. But, not using the plugin isn't an option because it's just so awesome.

What I want to do is load a different background for Firefox and not any other browser.. How do I accomplish this with CSS, or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a conditional comments to load a different style sheet or detect the browser with jQuery:

---

```
if ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version >= "1.8" )                     
    $("body").css("background-image", "firefox-background.jpg" );
```

Comment: why do you check firefox version?

Comment: You don't have to. I just added it in to show that you can detect browser versions with jQuery as well.

Comment: You need to explicitly put the `url`.

Comment: Worx.  Thanks so much.  Interstellar_Coder was right though, you do need to specify the url.

Answer (score 0):

Although i discourage this, here's some rough code

```
var imageUrl = 'your url'; 
if( $.browser.mozilla ) 
    $('#yourelement').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')' ); 
else 
    $('#yourelement').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')' );
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use some browser detection plugin. Also this ( and lots of other things ) can be done with head.js ( http://headjs.com/ )